# Why isn't my Roblox localScript enabling a GUI when a tool is equipped?

Tags: lua, roblox

Im new to Roblox scripting and im not sure why this isn't working. I want a localScript that will set a GUI to enabled on the player's screen to run when a tool is equipped. [Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aPcy.png)

Code:

```lua
local tool = script.Parent
local CAD = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.CAD

local function onEquipped()
    CAD.Enabled = true
end

local function onUnequipped()
    CAD.Enabled = false
end

tool.Equipped:Connect(onEquipped)
tool.Unequipped:Connect(onUnequipped)
```

Output:

```bash
Infinite yield possible on 'cloud_218303841.Model.GUIs.SignalGUI.Scripts:WaitForChild("Mode")'
```

I've attached a screenshot of my Explorer at the top. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually, this error doesn't look like it's coming from this code sample

Comment: @Kylaaa Well i'd love to know what other script its coming from then because thats my only script in my game (PlayerSetup has nothing at the moment)

Comment: The error happens in that plugin: https://www.roblox.com/library/218303841/ROAD-ACCESSORIES-POWER-LINES-UPDATE?Category=Plugins

Comment: As for your UI, when you say "enabled" do you mean that the UI doesn't appear?